# Send email to AD group - workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, email

How can the system send an email to an AD group? This is what id like to accomplish: To create a workflow/piece/something that can be used for "announcements" which can be in the form of an email, to let the organization(via ad group" that the office is open/close/etc - i would like to be able to enter a Subject, then the body of the message.

thank you

Comment: Is a dev approach an option for you? Dev would be the cleaner way here. Workflows (even if often used this way, unfortunately) are not intended for such purposes.

Comment: Yes it is - what are you thinking....?

Comment: A simple Web part with input fields Subject/Body/To (or "To" would be a setting) can easily do the job. Not more than a few hours to develop/test/deploy in a clean way.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but - how are you able to edit the Web Part?

Comment: You'd need to develop a new Web part from scratch, and deploy it as a WSP package... That means a developper, Visual Studio, etc.

Comment: got it. Wouldnt i be able to Embed Code - and just add a form?

Comment: I don't think so, as sending an email requires server-code to be hosted somewhere... so you need to deploy something on a server (the SP server in case of a WSP development).

Comment: Which would be "easier" or more simple to do? i have access to a developer but not familiar with how to work in SharePoint. Guess my goal is to figure out how to do it and sit down with our developer ..... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to create a list with a Subject and Message field. Attach a workflow to it, which fires on new item creation and supply the required email.

This way you would have all the emails sent in the list and can be archived for future reference.

Edit:

The subject and message can be selected using the `Lookup for String` dialog.

[image]

Comment: What would the workflow look like?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I've done this in my environment and the message does not go out to the group.  I added a cc field so users can respond to the poster, and *that* person receives the message, but the group does not.  So I enabled `external users` in Exchange, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my workplace, and the most flexible way is to (unfortunately) add the alert on an announcement standard list manually.

The reason is that even tho there are methods to use the AD group as a recipient for automatic alerts, you will have the result that nobody can remove the alert you have set. It will look like one alert set on a single entity.

Setting them manually for all (in my case thankfully it was a few hundreds) gave the process the natural flexibility since every user could edit without causing any trouble.

I understand that to do it for 300-400 users is not the same as for 2000-5000 users or more.

Comment: HI Susan, could you explain in a bit more detail how you did it? i'm really having a hard time with this task.

Comment: You use the announcements and as a admin for the site collection (or site owner) you go to the alerts and assign alerts to all employees, (I did it in batch of 10 since the box for the users is not unlimited). Obviously any new employee must be added manually. Read also this on why my assumption that it can be done in another way it does not work in SP 2013 http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/10/setting-sharepoint-alerts-on-active-directory-security-groups/